# windows service publish in visual studio

Tags: wcf, publish

I have a **WCF** project  and I have create another project which will install this **WCF** as a **windows service**.

Now I want to get the **release artifacts** of this windows service. Normally for other project I just do a publish using visual studio and get the artifacts.

How do I create the release artifacts for windows service?

Answer (score 1):

for windows service program, just release the .exe file and the system admin will install the windows service with 'installUtil.exe' from .net framework